# How can I disable the "Getting Windows Ready" message when Windows shuts down?

Tags: windows-10, freeze, shutdown, deep-freeze

At work, we use Deep Freeze to restore the state of Windows every time the computer shuts down. In Windows 7 this worked great, but in Windows 10 the computer will sometimes get stuck on "Getting Windows Ready" when you shut the computer down.

A fix for the hanging would also solve the problem, but since the Windows image gets reset anyway, I would think that we could just disable the entire thing. Is there an option (such as a policy or registry value) that would allow us to do that?

Comment: This screen normally only happens after an feature update has been installed.  The screen itself cannot be disabled.  You will have to determine the proceeding events that causes the hang.  I assume your using a version of Deep Freeze that actually supports Windows 10.  Can you confirm that is the case?

Answer (score 0):

This process occurs after Windows has installed certain types of patches. If Deep Freeze is resetting the computer each time it is rebooted, and then the computer is reinstalling a patch (or patches), you've got your problem right there.

Faronics has guides on how to configured Windows Updates when running Deep Freeze. These would probably be worth checking out. Here are the few a quick Google search revealed:

- http://www.faronics.com/document-library/document/how-to-manage-windows-updates-with-deep-freeze/
- https://faronics.kayako.com/knowledgebase/article/View/297/8/how-are-windows-updates-handled-on-deep-freeze-protected-computers