# Windows 10 64 bit - Stuck "Getting Windows ready" after (possibly failed) software update

Tags: windows, windows-10, 64-bit, windows-update

**I've read a number of related questions that aren't quite my question...**

- [Windows 10 Getting Windows Ready Message](https://superuser.com/questions/1189160/windows-10-getting-windows-ready-message) **Q:** ...how can I get computer to stop showing me this screen? **[ie. User simply does not want to wait 45mins for OS update installs]**
- [Windows 10 64 bit stuck at getting ready](https://superuser.com/questions/951822/windows-10-64-bit-stuck-at-getting-ready/1279601#1279601) **Q:** [From a new OS install] But after reboot, the system stuck at the "Getting Ready" screen forever. **[ie. This user has never been able to log into the OS after install**]
- [How can I disable the "Getting Windows Ready" message when Windows shuts down?](https://superuser.com/questions/1164313/how-can-i-disable-the-getting-windows-ready-message-when-windows-shuts-down) **Q:** User is looking for a way to bypass "Getting Windows ready" screen on shut down / restart presumably because they will reload its state directly from a software called "Deep Freeze" instead. **[ie. User wants to bypass OS procedure that is working as intended]**

My Windows 10 64bit OS was recently 'refresh' *(That's "Windows" for the 'Programs' folder is deleted, registry is recreated, and windows is reinstalled without deleting any other files on the machine)*. After the 'refresh', I've been able to log in and use the PC for a number of days. Then once I was assumably stuck on the blue screen with the dots moving in a circle, etc:

```
Getting Windows ready
Don't turn off your computer
```

It was stuck for a number of hours, but I eventually restarted the machine and it booted normally and I was able to use again for the last week.

Some time within the week I remember investigating my windows update, I noticed that I had an update that was getting stuck and wouldn't complete normally. I don't recall if I had been able to reboot the PC after that point.

Last night I rebooted the machine, and this time it has been stuck on the screen mentioned above for over 8-10+ hrs, **so I suspect that the PC is now in an erroneous state.**

I've now attempted to restart the machine a number of times including into safe mode *(by forcing it into 'automatic repair' by hard booting the machine 3 times during the boot process)* and it always comes back to the blue screen mentioned above.

**How do I recover my machine from this state?**

*(Ideally least intrusive without a format/reinstall, etc)*

Comment: This certainly looks like a duplicate of the other questions that you linked to. It might help us find an answer if you can explain what is different about your problem.

Comment: Hi @Blackwood. I've attempted to restate the question above with more details and how it differentiates from the other questions researched and linked to. Thanks.

Comment: Admittedly I'm seeing a ton more questions in the related section that might actually help me out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it! From another 'licensed' Windows 10 PC...

**Boot Windows 10 Installer from a USB:**

- Download this tool: [Create Windows 10 installation media](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10?tduid=(cc5cbdef235355eda514ae4a295d7886)(259740)(2542549)(UUwpUdUnU50931YYw)(dwp))
- Install the tool to a USB stick/drive
- Reboot the machine and smash F8 or F12 to get the machine to boot from the USB
- When you get to the screen that says "Install Windows 10" there will be a link in the lower left hand corner that says "Repair" **<- click that!**
- ***Look here for some screenshots:*** [5. Use a Windows 10 installation drive and the Command Prompt](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/4-ways-boot-safe-mode-windows-10)

*(There are a number of tools you can use here, but **System Restore** was the only that worked for me.)*

[image: **Screenshots of recovery options from USB Intaller**]

**Recovery options *that worked for me*:**

- **Restore back far enough to where the system was stable;** I had to do it twice to stop the blue screen issue. First time I just stepped one restore point back. The second time I went back as far as possible, which was a "Critical Windows 10 Update" right after my 'refresh'
- [DrMoishe Pippik](https://superuser.com/questions/1279604/windows-10-64-bit-stuck-getting-windows-ready-after-possibly-failed-softwa/1279682#answer-1279678) **suggests doing another 'refresh'**, which likely would have worked as well. Because I just did one of those, I know that a restore point was definitely faster and retained most of my installed apps.

---

**Other tools you can try from the USB Installer that DIDN'T work for me...**

- Startup Repair
- Startup Settings *(for safe mode)*

---

**Bonuses:**

**Here's a strategy to "BLOCK" automated updates to Windows 10 Home Editions:**

- [HOW TO STOP AUTO UPDATES IN WINDOWS 10](https://www.bouncegeek.com/stop-auto-updates-in-windows-10-5248736148/)

**Here's how to reset Windows Update if it gets into an erroneous state:**

- Clear the contents of the [Software Distribution folder](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/software-distribution-folder-in-windows), [reset the Catroot2 folder](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/catroot-catroot2-folder-reset-windows) and then run Windows Update again.

Reference: [How to install Windows 10 from USB with UEFI support](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-windows-10-usb-bootable-media-uefi-support)

Answer (score 1):

Even though you wish to avoid reinstallation, that is probably the safest option, since it appears the refresh process was stuck or interrupted more than once. This ensures that *all* needed system files are in place. It may well be **faster** to do the full reinstallation than trying to refresh Windows from the active HDD.

Download the [latest Windows ISO and installation media creation tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10), create a USB instllation and [perform a reinstallation whilst keeping data files](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-reinstall-windows-10-without-losing-data/).

Comment: Thanks @DrMoishe this is essentially what I ended up doing, except that I ended up having a restore point that worked! Thanks for the help! I definitely would have done another 'refresh' if that didn't work (using a USB installer)